# How to pass a boolean method to another method in Java

Tags: java

I have a class with two methods (one is boolean) and I want to pass that boolean method to the other one. So, if the movement of the Rook piece on a chessboard is valid, then proceed to the drawing of the piece:

```
public class Rook extends AbstractPiece {

    @Override
    public boolean isMoveValid(int srcRow, int srcCol, int destRow, int destCol) {
        boolean valid;
        if ((destRow == srcRow) || (destCol == srcCol)) {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }

@Override
    public void draw() {

        if (isMoveValid == true){ //or if(valid == true) or something like that
            //draw stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not clear at all what you are seeking

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the method to another method"?  The `draw` method can *call* the `isMoveValid` method, it just needs to pass 4 `int` values to it when doing so.  Though it seems kind of backwards that `draw` would be checking if the move is valid.  Generally whatever *invokes* `draw` (the game engine logic) would have already checked that before invoking it.

Comment: isMoveValid is a method and you're not passing any arguments. so your call will be  if(isMoveValid(2,3,4,5) == true) { }

Comment: Thank you guys! What if I want to check the if statement with the "valid" boolean variable instead? Do I have to make it global?

Comment: @deadpixels if `valid` is a class filed then it should work too, just make sure to call `isMoveValid` before calling `draw` so that its value is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call isMoveValid in your second method with valid parameters. Ex:

```
    @Override
    public void draw() {

        if (isMoveValid(1,1,2,2) == true){ //or if(valid == true) or something like that
            //draw stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: if (isMoveValid(1,1,2,2) ) is gonna be enough

Comment: i mean there is no need to mention == true

Comment: Yes either way will work.  Sometimes it's better to specify == true for readability but it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

isMoveValid is a method while you're using it like a variable. your code will be

```
public class Rook extends AbstractPiece {

    @Override
    public boolean isMoveValid(int srcRow, int srcCol, int destRow, int destCol) {
        boolean valid;
        if ((destRow == srcRow) || (destCol == srcCol)) {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }

@Override
    public void draw() {

        if (isMoveValid(1,2,2,1)){ // or your requied values
            //draw stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (isMoveValid(1,1,2,2) ) is gonna be enough

Comment: it depends upon his requirement what value should be there. it can be any valid int

Comment: the return type is boolean and no it does not depend on his requiremtn

Comment: @ZohaibAslam: His point was that you don't need the `== true` part.  "Is Valid" is a boolean concept, it's either true or false already.

Answer (score 0):

So like  David said, you must pass 4 int values to isMoveValid method

your code in draw method must be something like this

```
public void draw() {

        if (isMoveValid(srcRow,srcCol,destRow,destCol)){ 
            //draw stuff
        }
    }
```

Where srcRow,srcCol,destRow,destCol are 4 integers